# How to make column to subtract from ONE cell

Tags: excel, vba, powerbi, powerquery

I'm trying to use Power Query to make a table that automatically subtracts A1 (10) from each cell in column B. The results will be in column C.

In regular excel, this would simply be B2-$A$2 and so on bur I'm not sure how to do that in PQ. Thanks in advance!
c
[image]

I tried looking it up online but those didnt subtract from one specific cell but from the corresponding cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To refer to the first cell in Column A, you use a construction like:

```
TableName[ColumnName]{index into column}
```

The 'Index' in PQ is zero-based, so more likely:

```
=#"Previous Step"[A]{0}
```

Or, in this case the previous step is `#"Changed Type" (as you can see from the Screen Shot:

[image]

Equivalent M-Code:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"A", Int64.Type}, {"B", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "C", each [B]-#"Changed Type"[A]{0}, Int64.Type)
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Yes, it will work without specifying a data type at that point. And, in this simple example, the extra memory used by not setting the data type as `Int64.Type` would be trivial.  Suggest you do some research as to the pros and cons of setting data types in PQ for better understanding. Depending on what I am doing, I may not set the data types until the end of a query. But they can be useful in earlier steps also. Especially since PQ does always automatically do type conversions as does Excel.